# Notebook ran as batch and CloudDeploy

Tags: scripting, cloud-deploy

i am new to mathematica, and i am trying to run a notebook as batch job(i will elaborate on this later). According to the documentation, running mathematica from command line using the -script parameter will run as batch job. it also mentions .wl files but i dont know how to create them.

this is what i have in the notebook:

https://pastebin.com/DTkSRZy4

as you can see, other than the first i have added some sample plots. when i run this from cmd (i am on windows 10), i run it this way:

C:> "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\math.exe" -script "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Mathematica\final.nb"

and i get only text, and nothing else (no cloud link also). but, if i run it from notebook -> evaluate notebook, i see everything rendered and also i get the cloud link. if needed, i can split the single file to several different files.

so, my questions are:

1. how to write a simple .wl file (or .m as i understood) to call the different files to execute them in the wl script (if i understood the concept of batch execution in mathematica)?
2. how to print out also the cloud link when calling it from cli?
3. probably a stupid question, but: should the cloud link be available when running it from cli?

Comment: Copy your code as simple text and paste it in a text file (say `script.wl`).  Then execute it in a command line with `wolframscript -f script.wl`

Comment: In Mathematica "File / Save As..." and select "Wolfram Language Package (*.wl).

Comment: Ok, that is the first point. Will it print out the cloud link when running it from cmd? I am currently not in front of my desk to try this out.